# Правильные ударения в словах "грушевый" и "сливовый"

Tags: грамотная-речь, фонетика

Очень режет слух, когда говорят "грушОвый" или "сливОвый". Или так все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно - грушевый и слИвовый, других вариантов словари пока не разрешают.

Но и к "неправильным" вариантам стоит присмотреться. Ещё не так давно в одном ряду со сливовым и грушевым стояло вИшневый. Кажется, даже при Чехове сад был именно вИшневым. Сейчас так вряд ли кто скажет даже по ошибке.

Comment: Капли (лекарство) до сих пор "лавровИшневые".